Can't get all span tags inside div element using beautifulsoup
I am scraping the product details page text on Amazon, but I get the data back as bullet list. I want to have the data added as a column next to other scraped data.
csv export
Amazon Product Details
A part of the code that is working
def get_availability(soup):
try:
    available = soup.find("div", attrs={'id':'availability'})
    available = available.find("span").string.strip()

except AttributeError:
    available = "Not Available" 

return available

I mimicked this part of the code like above, but it is not working as expected
# Function to extract Product Details
def get_pd(soup):
    try:
        pd = soup.find("div", attrs={'id':'detailBullets_feature_div'}).text.strip()
        pd = pd.find("span").string.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        pd = ""

    return pd

When I remove this part of the code
 pd = pd.find("span").string.strip()

I get the bullet list, but the result is not how I want. The result should be placed next to each other instead of vertical.

You can try:
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.amazon.nl/-/en/Multivitamins-minerals-high-dosage-containing/dp/B075RCPZ3P/ref=sr_1_6?crid=1WFDIDCT1PXE8&dib=eyJ2IjoiMSJ9.Pv8fNYUtGuBYdebOTisLFgv9KuLU_Pb1FMnnf4Q8FMLHlQivImbxYNVwbRBJ2YOA6M-zlNIHqgWqDzMZfhYePmXlUI15lwwP6VQTH7egA0p_Maz2vsBzdbYZCpZmEZX1O2NaH2B50BXlPQfmQyn_X3Zy_qiZ4TJRKc9rv30-oUhlPDIxXKWa_2Sr1t7BR7hl3Ks2zQd0ZmaBIX3w2M2o183BmuHvi9haYAdE916Rjz8VK7xBbRyW5VhaqJlYpO1iEsn5OhL9HTbBaqTKQ4eZXEUam3py0rWWnWBWb9B7b54.b_p-s2SKiuGSEs7A04s5RAxdHAwHKRMbXPi3OPg-leM&dib_tag=se&keywords=vitamine&qid=1726325837&sprefix=vitamine%2Caps%2C225&sr=8-6"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")

details = soup.select(
    'h2:-soup-contains("Product details") ~ div > ul, h2:-soup-contains("Product details") ~ ul'
)

data = {"title": soup.title.text}
for ul in details:
    for li in ul.find_all("li", recursive=False):
        t = re.sub(
            r"\s{2,}", " ", li.text.strip().replace("\u200f", "").replace("\u200e", "")
        )
        k, v = t.split(":", maxsplit=1)
        data[k] = v

df = pd.DataFrame([data])
print(df)

Prints:



title
Is discontinued by manufacturer
Product Dimensions
Date First Available
Manufacturer
ASIN
Manufacturer reference
Country of origin
Guaranteed software updates until
Best Sellers Rank
Customer reviews




Multivitamins and minerals high dosage - 450 tablets containing all A-Z vitamins - Calcium, Biotin, Selenium, Zinc, Folic acid, Vitamin A, B1, B2, B3, B5, B6, B12, C, D3, E : Amazon.nl: Health & Personal Care
No
6 x 6 x 10 cm; 225 g
5 Jun. 2020
Gloryfeel
B075RCPZ3P
gf-multiv-450
Germany
unknown
22 in Health & Personal Care (See Top 100 in Health & Personal Care) 1 in Multivitamins Nutritional Supplements
4.4 4.4 out of 5 stars 18,107 ratings



